# Function with string parameter

Tags: php, sql

I have function

```
function count_where($param, $value)
{
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM vote WHERE '$param'='$value'");
    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $data['TOTAL'];
}
```

and try to call it

```
count_where('picture','black circle')
```

where picture has varchar type (in MySQL). It doesn't work.
This

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM vote WHERE picture='black circle'");
 $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo $data['TOTAL'];
```

work;

Comment: You have to load the db connection from within the function.

Comment: Of course the second work... How are you trying to pass the values into the first function? Did not really understand...

Comment: I am surprised that the second works as array-indexes are case-sensitive, so `somearray['TOTAL']` is not the same as `somearray['total']`.

Comment: What ended up being the problem?

Comment: backticks ` instead of apostrophes '

Answer (score 3):

if you want to encapsulate the column name, use backticks `` ` `` instead of apostrophes `'`

But be careful, watch out for sql injection. Before running the query you can better do:

```
$param = mysql_real_escape_string($param);
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
```

Comment: Who ever gave the downvote: any reason you would like to share ?

Answer (score 1):

replace single quotes in column name with backticks like this:

```
function count_where($param, $value)
{
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM vote WHERE `$param`='$value'");
    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $data['total'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM vote WHERE ".$param."='".$value."'");
```

I think this will give you the answer

Comment: Why would you use concatenation for `$param`, but not `$value`?